# VBA Class converter to eliminate strings being used as valid values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to avoid strings being passed around as a valid value. The ability to make a mistake is too high for my taste and the solution that I've come up with is to use an `Enum`. This provides the benefit of intellisense when trying to use the values. Similar to typing `sheet1.Visible =`  which gives the valid options a worksheet property with its type declared `As SimpleSpanBracing` allows the valid values be chosen. Now when I need to use something or to `Get` or `Let` a value I use the converter to ensure that I'm not going to mistakenly mix up casing, `ends only` or `midspan`, and accidentally get a false positive/negative.

Is there anything that I'm missing or haven't guarded against?

Enumeration with valid options. `notSet` is an option because I don't want to assume the default value. I'd prefer to see what's causing the issue and how it came about.

```
Public Enum SimpleSpanBracing
    notSet
    endsonly
    midspan
    thirdspan
End Enum
```

`SpanBracingConverter` Class that does the actual converting. I'm not concerned with getting a value that hasn't been set, but setting it to an invalid issues will cause an error to be raised, avoiding a false positive/negative mentioned above.

```
Private Const spanEnd As String = "ENDS ONLY"
Private Const spanMid As String = "MIDSPAN"
Private Const spanThird As String = "1/3 SPAN"
Private Const INVALID_INPUT As Long = 5

Public Function ToString(ByVal value As SimpleSpanBracing) As String
    If value = endsonly Then
        ToString = spanEnd
    ElseIf value = midspan Then
        ToString = spanMid
    ElseIf value = thirdspan Then
        ToString = spanThird
    Else
        Err.Raise INVALID_INPUT, "SpanBracingConverter.ToString()", "Invalid input supplied"
    End If
End Function
Public Function ToEnum(ByVal value As String) As SimpleSpanBracing
    value = UCase$(value)
    If value = spanEnd Then
        ToEnum = endsonly
    ElseIf value = spanMid Then
        ToEnum = midspan
    ElseIf value = spanThird Then
        ToEnum = thirdspan
    Else
        Err.Raise INVALID_INPUT, "SpanBracingConverter.ToEnum()", "Invalid input supplied"
    End If
End Function
Public Function ValidateString(ByVal value As String) As String
    ValidateString = ToString(ToEnum(value))
End Function
```

What follows are the unit tests I've created with [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) to test this converter.

```
'@TestMethod
Public Sub ValidInputs()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim sut As SpanBracingConverter
    Set sut = New SpanBracingConverter

    'Act:
    Dim lowerEnd As SimpleSpanBracing
    lowerEnd = sut.ToEnum("ends only")
    Dim upperEnd As SimpleSpanBracing
    upperEnd = sut.ToEnum("ENDS ONLY")
    Dim lowerMid As SimpleSpanBracing
    lowerMid = sut.ToEnum("midspan")
    Dim upperMid As SimpleSpanBracing
    upperMid = sut.ToEnum("MIDSPAN")
    Dim lowerThird As SimpleSpanBracing
    lowerThird = sut.ToEnum("1/3 span")
    Dim upperThird As SimpleSpanBracing
    upperThird = sut.ToEnum("1/3 SPAN")

    Dim endInput As String
    endInput = sut.ToString(endsonly)
    Dim midInput As String
    midInput = sut.ToString(midspan)
    Dim thirdInput As String
    thirdInput = sut.ToString(thirdspan)

    'Assert:
    Assert.areequal SimpleSpanBracing.endsonly, lowerEnd
    Assert.areequal SimpleSpanBracing.endsonly, upperEnd
    Assert.areequal SimpleSpanBracing.midspan, lowerMid
    Assert.areequal SimpleSpanBracing.midspan, upperMid
    Assert.areequal SimpleSpanBracing.thirdspan, lowerThird
    Assert.areequal SimpleSpanBracing.thirdspan, upperThird

    Assert.areequal "ENDS ONLY", endInput
    Assert.areequal "MIDSPAN", midInput
    Assert.areequal "1/3 SPAN", thirdInput

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub InvalidStringInput()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:

    'Act:
    With New SpanBracingConverter
        .ToEnum "fail"
    End With

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub UnsetEnumValue()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:

    'Act:
    With New SpanBracingConverter
        .ToString SimpleSpanBracing.notSet
    End With

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub LargestAssignedEnumValue()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:

    'Act:
    With New SpanBracingConverter
        .ToString 4
    End With

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub InputMatchesOutputCaseInsensitive()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:

    'Act:

    'Assert:
    With New SpanBracingConverter
        Assert.areequal "ENDS ONLY", .ValidateString("ENDS ONLY")
        Assert.areequal "ENDS ONLY", .ValidateString("ends only")
        Assert.areequal "MIDSPAN", .ValidateString("MIDSPAN")
        Assert.areequal "MIDSPAN", .ValidateString("midspan")
        Assert.areequal "1/3 SPAN", .ValidateString("1/3 SPAN")
        Assert.areequal "1/3 SPAN", .ValidateString("1/3 span")
    End With

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

---

***Edit:*** [My followup question, Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191441/vba-class-converter-to-eliminate-strings-being-used-as-valid-values-part2) continues my work on the converter class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Enum

An `Enum` is essentially a *type*, it has *members*. Members should be `PascalCase` - I'd change the `alllowercase` casing to respect that convention:

```
Public Enum SimpleSpanBracing
    NotSet = 0
    EndsOnly
    MidSpan
    ThirdSpan
End Enum
```

I would also make the `NotSet` value *explicitly* `0`, because otherwise someone could very well think the enum would look prettier if all its members were listed alphabetically, and that would royally mess things up.

---

#### The Converter

The job of that class is essentially to *map* strings to enum values, and enum values to strings. Whenever I use the word "map", I automatically think of a `Dictionary`.

Picture your enum with 200 members. I doubt you find that `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...` conditional structure nice & neat now, huh?

A `Select Case...Case...Case...` block would be better IMO, but still rather annoying to maintain, given you essentially need the same blocks twice.

I'd go with a `Private Dictionary` - keyed with the strings and valued with the enums.

Then I'd have another `Private Dictionary`, keyed with [a string representation of] the enum values, and valued with the corresponding strings.

In the class' `Initialize` handler, I'd populate *one* of them, and then iterate it to automatically populate the other; of course the two methods would be implemented in their own dedicated `Private Sub` procedures, and the string constants would no longer serve a purpose.

Then, `ToString` and `ToEnum` would end up being as straightforward as it gets:

```
Public Function ToString(ByVal value As SimpleSpanBracing) As String
    If Not StringForEnum.Exists(CStr(value)) Then
        ThrowInvalidArgument "ToString", CStr(value)
        'Exit Function
    End If
    ToString = StringForEnum(CStr(value))
End Function

Public Function ToEnum(ByVal value As String) As SimpleSpanBracing
    If Not EnumForString.Exists(value) Then
        ThrowInvalidArgument "ToEnum", value
        'Exit Function
    End If
    ToEnum = EnumForString(value)
End Function
```

I'd have a dedicated `ThrowInvalidArgument` procedure responsible for throwing the *invalid argument* error, and move the `INVALID_INPUT` declaration there... or just remove it and inline the message string.

```
Private Sub ThrowInvalidArgument(ByVal source As String, ByVal value As String)
    Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me) & "." & source, _
        "Invalid input '" & value & "' was supplied."
End Sub
```

The purpose of `ValidateString` doesn't strike me as super-obvious just by the name; my brain somehow expects "ValidateFoo" to either return a `Boolean` telling me whether I've supplied a valid `Foo`, or to throw an error given an invalid value. That method is really just a "round-trip" utility function that, IMO, should be inlined at call sites.

As a bonus of using that dictionary approach, you could expose a `Property Get` member that returns an array containing all the valid enum values, and another that returns all the valid strings. More on that in a minute.

---

#### The Tests

IMO all the `Dim` statements are cluttering the "Act" part of the tests and making it harder than necessary to read the actual "acting" executable statements.

Rubberduck's `IAssert` interface exposes a convenient [`SequenceEquals`](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.Main/ComClientLibrary/Abstract/UnitTesting/IAssert.cs#L119-L129) method that you can use to iterate and compare array elements; instead of making a series of `Assert.AreEqual` calls, you could have the converter expose a `Property Get` member that gives you all the valid strings as an array, a `Property Get` member that gives you all the valid enum values as another array, and then iterate one array to populate a "result" array by invoking your SUT/conversion in one single place (in that loop) - and then make one single `Assert` call to compare the expected vs. the actual resulting array.