# VBA Class converter to eliminate strings being used as valid values, part2

Tags: vba

[My original question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191103/vba-class-converter-to-eliminate-strings-being-used-as-valid-values) got an answer that helped me revise my code. Below is updated code with a converter that has a few more choices.

These enum members are prefaced with `ss` since numbers aren't allowed as starting characters.

```
'SectionSetConverter Class
Public Enum SectionSets
    NotSet
    ss14x6
    ss12x8
    ss12x6
    ss10x10
    ss10x8
    ss10x6
    ss8x8
    Aggregate
    FullList
End Enum

'@Folder("Converters")
Option Explicit

Private StringForEnum As Dictionary
Private EnumForString As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    PopulateDictionaries
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateDictionaries()
    Set EnumForString = New Dictionary
    EnumForString.CompareMode = TextCompare

    EnumForString.Add "14x6", ss14x6
    EnumForString.Add "12x8", ss12x8
    EnumForString.Add "12x6", ss12x6
    EnumForString.Add "10x10", ss10x10
    EnumForString.Add "10x8", ss10x8
    EnumForString.Add "10x6", ss10x6
    EnumForString.Add "8x8", ss8x8
    EnumForString.Add "Aggregate", Aggregate
    EnumForString.Add vbNullString, FullList

    Set StringForEnum = New Dictionary
    EnumForString.CompareMode = TextCompare
    Dim i As Variant
    For Each i In EnumForString.Keys
        StringForEnum.Add EnumForString.Item(i), i
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ToEnum(ByVal value As String) As SectionSets
    value = UCase$(value)

    If Not EnumForString.Exists(value) Then
        ThrowInvalidArgument "ToEnum", value
    End If

    ToEnum = EnumForString(value)
End Function

Public Function ToString(ByVal value As SectionSets)
    If Not StringForEnum.Exists(value) Then
        ThrowInvalidArgument "ToString", CStr(value)
    End If

    ToString = StringForEnum(value)
End Function

Private Sub ThrowInvalidArgument(ByVal source As String, ByVal value As String)
    Err.Raise 5, Information.TypeName(Me) & "." & source, "Invalid input '" & value & "' was supplied."
End Sub

Public Property Get Enums() As Variant
    Enums = EnumForString.Items
End Property

Public Property Get Strings() As Variant
    Strings = EnumForString.Keys
End Property
```

***Note***: The annotation `'@Folder("Converters")` helps organize all my converters into a "Folder" for easier viewing with the Code Explorer of the [RubberduckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/) add-in.

---

Following the advice of @MathieuGuindon I created the private `Dictionary` (Requires early reference to be set in the VBE by going to *Tools>References>Microsoft Scripting Runtime*) for each of the values.

There's now only a single list to maintain. The population of the the dictionary and iteration of the `Keys` to populate the second list guarantees that they won't become out of sync and will reflect the correct Key Value Pair (KVP).

The above exposed functions `ToEnum` and `ToString` convert the parameter to the correct value. Any invalid information causes `ThrowInvalidArgument` to be called and raise the appropriate error.

Lastly the properties that allow for simpler unit tests, which coincidentally follow.

```
'@TestMethod
Public Sub ValidInputs()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim sut As SectionSetConverter
    Set sut = New SectionSetConverter

    Dim converterEnums As Variant
    converterEnums = sut.Enums

    Dim converterStrings As Variant
    converterStrings = sut.Strings

    Dim actualStrings As Variant
    ReDim actualStrings(LBound(converterStrings) To UBound(converterStrings))

    Dim actualEnums As Variant
    ReDim actualEnums(LBound(converterStrings) To UBound(converterStrings))

    'Act:
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(actualStrings) To UBound(actualStrings)
        actualStrings(i) = sut.ToString(converterEnums(i))
    Next

    For i = LBound(actualEnums) To UBound(actualEnums)
        actualEnums(i) = sut.ToEnum(converterStrings(i))
    Next

    'Assert:
    Assert.sequenceequals converterStrings, actualStrings
    Assert.sequenceequals converterEnums, actualEnums

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub UnsetEnumValue()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:

    'Act:
    With New SectionSetConverter
        .ToString SectionSets.NotSet
    End With

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub LargestAssignedEnumValue()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:

    'Act:
    With New SectionSetConverter
        .ToString 10
    End With

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If
End Sub
```

Previously the test `ValidInputs` had an awkward feel to it. Adding members to SectionSet would have required me to update the unit test every time. Now if a member is added their respective valid values are already tested thanks to the `Enums` and `Strings` properties on `SectionSetConverter`.

Are there any other parts I can improve on? I've thought about creating an `IConverter` class and having each converter `Implements` it but am undecided on the benefits of doing so presently.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the constant `vbTextCompare` for your CompareMode on your objects so a user can simply choose if they want to use early or late binding.

Mostly, I am confused about the `Enum`. When we initialize we end up with -

```
StringForEnum as Dictionary
StringForEnum(1) = 1
StringForEnum(2) = 2
StringForEnum(3) = 3
StringForEnum(4) = 4
StringForEnum(5) = 5
StringForEnum(6) = 6
StringForEnum(7) = 7
StringForEnum(8) = 8
StringForEnum(9) = 9

Enums as Variant
Enums(0) = 1
Enums(1) = 2
Enums(2) = 3
Enums(3) = 4
Enums(4) = 5
Enums(5) = 6
Enums(6) = 7
Enums(7) = 8
Enums(8) = 9

EnumForString as Dictionary
EnumForString(1) = "14x6"
EnumForString(2) = "12x8"
EnumForString(3) = "12x6"
EnumForString(4) = "10x10"
EnumForString(5) = "10x8"
EnumForString(6) = "10x6"
EnumForString(7) = "8x8"
EnumForString(8) = "Aggregate"
EnumForString(9) = ""

Strings as Variant
Strings(0) = "14x6"
Strings(1) = "12x8"
Strings(2) = "12x6"
Strings(3) = "10x10"
Strings(4) = "10x8"
Strings(5) = "10x6"
Strings(6) = "8x8"
Strings(7) = "Aggregate"
Strings(8) = ""
```

Right, but your properties `Enums` and `Strings` don't have a `Let` method, which means it cannot be changed while running.

You also notice that your variants start at `0` and your dictionaries start at `1`. So why are these duplicated in such a way that the Dictionary is needed, considering it requires a reference?

So, I'm not sure, but I'll assume the integer references you want start at 1 instead of 0. So this all can be accomplished with just one property and one constant -

```
Const STRING_VALUES = "14x6,12x8,12x6,10x10,10x8,10x6,8x8,Aggregate,"

Private Strings As Variant

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
    Strings = Split(STRING_VALUES, ",")
End Sub

Public Property Get ToString(value As Long)
    ToString = Strings(value - 1)
End Property
```

I also don't know why you would need to expose a property that returns the entire variable array - isn't that why it's in a `Class`? So you don't need to store it in a different object?

Maybe I'm missing the point, but this all seems a bit overkill.

Comment: I don't expose any `Let` property since I don't intend for them to be changed when running. I hadn't though of the `0`/`1` difference in variant and dictionary. Although that's taken care of with the `NotSet` enumeration option. I'll look into implementing your shorthand string version and see if it grows on me.